# How to push a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to know how can i store data in an array like that in order to do it with push function.

here is the code

```
var data_array =  [];
```

and data look like that

```
var my_data = {
              "2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2012":{"name":"Agents","total":1997,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2013":{"name":"Coachs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2014":{"name":"Formateurs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2015":{"name":"Quality Analysts","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"}
                        };
```

any help to change this way of inserting and use push function .

Comment: what data you want to push ?

Comment: What do you want your array to look like after you've done the push?

Comment: data_array.push(my_data); is that what you need?

Comment: @MaheshSapkal  , well guys  imy data is an array , and my data look like that what i need is to use the push function to store one row that looks like that "2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"} ,for example  : dara_array.push( "2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"})

Comment: I think you are missing "the code" because all I see is an array literal.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help,

You can loop through all the keys of the object and push each one into the array

```
var data_array =  [];  
var my_data = {
              "2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2012":{"name":"Agents","total":1997,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2013":{"name":"Coachs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2014":{"name":"Formateurs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2015":{"name":"Quality Analysts","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"}
};

var keysArray = Object.keys(my_data);

keysArray.forEach(function(key, index) {
  data_array.push({ key : my_data[key]});
});

console.log(data_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (wrap data in curly braces):

```
data_array.push( {"2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"} })
```

Comment: @nedaljedidi "not working" isn't terribly descriptive. Are you getting an error? Does the result appear different than you expect? In what way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Exactly what do you want. Anyway, I think that It works for you.

```
var personInfo = new Object();
var my_data = new Object();

personInfo.name = 'Team Leaders';
personInfo.total = 93;
personInfo.drilldown = 'true';

my_data.person1 = personInfo;
my_data.person2 = personInfo;

// confirm
var jsonType = JSON.stringify(my_data);
console.log(jsonType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
var data_array =  [];  
var my_data = {
              "2011":{"name":"Team Leaders","total":93,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2012":{"name":"Agents","total":1997,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2013":{"name":"Coachs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2014":{"name":"Formateurs","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"},
              "2015":{"name":"Quality Analysts","total":1188,"drilldown":"true"}
};
var data_keys= Object.keys(my_data);

data_keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = my_data[key];
    data_array.push(obj);
});
```